# Daylight savings time reminder?

Tags: email, sms, reminder

Is there a web app that will send me an email or SMS to remind me that US Daylight Savings Time is starting or ending?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*This is a Google Calendar solution, and includes instructions on how to add reminder notifications, since the basic US Holiday calendar doesn't allow you to change Calendar-level notifications.*

You can try using Google Calendar to set an event on your calendar every time [Daylight Savings time begins or ends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States). This works for events repeating on **the first Sunday in November** which is when Daylight Savings ends.

Here's how you can do it for Daylight Savings ending (in the fall).

1. Go to the day you'd like the event to start and click "Create Event"
2. Create an event titled "Daylight Savings time ends"
3. Set it to repeat "Monthly"
4. Repeat every: 12 months
5. Repeat by: "day of the week"
6. Starts on "11/4/2012"

The summary at the bottom should say "Every 12 months on the first Sunday" - this will make sure the even happens on the first Sunday, regardless of the actual date:

[image]

Once the event is created, just set the reminder notification to send you an email/SMS for whenever you'd like the reminder to be sent (this reminder can be sent minutes, hours, or days before the actual time change).

Repeat this process for the **second Sunday in March** which is when it starts back up again. There is no way to set an event to repeat 6 months on a different Sunday.

*Disclaimer: I work for Google, so my solutions tend to be Google-centric*

Comment: +1 Good solution, if you have a Google account.